# LINQ GroupBy - How to group?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code fragment:

```
List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
list.Add(new string[] { "A", "q", "t" });
list.Add(new string[] { "B", "w", "t" });
list.Add(new string[] { "B", "e", "r" });
list.Add(new string[] { "A", "r", "t" });
list.Add(new string[] { "B", "t", "e" });

var result = from item in list 
    group item by item[0] into g
    let count = g.Count()
    orderby count descending
    select new { Value = g.Key, Count = count};

foreach (var res in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " + res.Value + " Count: " + res.Count);
}
```

that product this result:

```
Value: B Count: 3
Value: A Count: 2
```

How can I get this result without too many foreach?

```
Values: A q t - Count 2  
Values: A r t - Count 2  
Values: B w t - Count 3  
Values: B e r - Count 3  
Values: B t e - Count 3
```

Comment: How come you have count `2` for `A q t`? Similarly counts for others with the data you provided?

Comment: The count 2 is because the letter "A" is present two time in the first column of the data. The letter "B" is present three time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following

```
var result = list.GroupBy(innerArray => innerArray[0])
    .SelectMany(
        grp => grp.Select(innerArray  => new
            {
                Values = innerArray, 
                Count = grp.Count()
             }));

foreach(var r in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Values: {0} - Count {1}", string.Join(" ", r.Values), r.Count);
}
```

This first groups by the first item of each array then uses `SelectMany` to flatten each group back into the original arrays and include the count.

This produces the exact order as your request, which might be a coincidence of your data.  You can throw a `OrderBy(g=>g.Count())` in there if you want to make sure it does a ascending order by the count.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is fto use a `SelectMany`

```
    var result =  list.GroupBy(x=> x[0])
                      .SelectMany(x=> x, 
                                  (x,xx)=> new {
                                                   Value=string.Join(" ",xx),  
                                                   Count = x.Count()
                                                });
```